# Doubt in this displacement-time graph

Tags: kinematics, time, distance, displacement

According to a book, this is a graph of **"a ball resting on a smooth floor is kicked which rebounds from a wall with reduced speed. It then moves to the opposite wall, which stops it."**

[image]

> My Question is **" How is it that when the time is negative, there is displacement increasing? How can time even be negative in the first place?"**

Comment: Hint: At what time does the ball bounce off the wall?

Comment: @PM2Ring Still how is it that the time is negative?

Comment: Because if the event happens at $t = 0$, then when will the ball exist on the smooth floor. It's not as if the ball came into existence the moment it is kicked etc. This is just a matter of convention, on how you 'label' time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative time means "before something happened".

In the graph, t=0 is the point in time where the ball hits the first wall. The things that happen before are shown to the left on the negative t axis.

The graph is not wrong because one can move the origin everywhere without changing the physical situation.

A more sensible choice would have been to put the origin at the start of the motion in both space and time.

If this is the exact pictures from the book, there however is another serious error.

Comment: Why is there a serious error?

Comment: The graph does not show the reduction of speed after the bounce.